# URL Encoding is breaking routing in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

If a user copies a url from my website like:

> www.mysite.com/#tag/Sometagtext%20(Sometagtext2)|card/somecardname/21

and posts it on another website, that other website encodes the string to:

> www.mysite.com/#tag/Sometext%20%28Sometext2%29%7Ccard/somecardname/21

When this new URL is used, the encoding is not being handled properly by `ExtJS` and the website is breaking.

I checked the tag value in **`onBeforeTagChange`** within **`MainController.js`** (see code) and it includes the card:

> sometagtext%20%28Sometagtext2%29%7Ccard/somecardname/21
>
> sometagtext (Sometagtext2)|card/somecardname/21 )

So, at the very least, the encoding of the multiple route delimiter from | to %7C is breaking the site since it can't parse the tags from the cards.

Where and how would I go about updating the router so that it decodes the URL before parsing it?

I'm using `ExtJS 6.0.2.437`

**Here is my code:**

```
Ext.define('APP.view.main.MainController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',

    alias: 'controller.main',

    routes: {
        'card/:card/:collection_id': {
            action: 'cardChange',
            before: 'beforeCardChange',
            conditions: {
                ':collection_id': '([0-9]+)'
            }
        },
        'card/:card': {
            action: 'cardChange',
            before: 'beforeCardChangeBase'

        },
        'tag/:tag': {
            action: 'onTagChange',
            before: 'onBeforeTagChange',
            conditions: {
                ':tag': '([%a-zA-Z0-9\.\\-\\_\\s,\(\)\/]+)'
            }
        }
    },
    onTagChange: function (tag) {

    },
    onBeforeTagChange: function (tag, action) {
        console.log(tag);
        tag = decodeURI(tag);
        console.log(tag);
    },
    /*  ...
        ...
        ...
    */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use **decodeURI()** before callback